# setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings returns Param Illegal

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm using the SDK version 4.11 and havent changed this code bit since 4.10:

```
int shootInterval = 2;
SettingsDefinitions.PhotoTimeIntervalSettings mSettings = new SettingsDefinitions.PhotoTimeIntervalSettings(255, shootInterval);
DJIApplication.getCameraInstance().setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings(mSettings, djiError -> {
    if (djiError == null) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Camera interval set to " + mSettings.getTimeIntervalInSeconds() + " seconds");
    } else {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "ERROR! Message: " + djiError.getDescription())
    }
});
```

The error I'm getting:

"Param Illegal"

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I talked with DJI Support and the issue is that on the Phantom 4 RTK the minimum interval is 3 and not 2 seconds.
2 months ago they promised to change the documentation but this never happened until today:
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera_DJICameraPhotoIntervalParam.html#djicamera_djicameraphotointervalparam_timeintervalinseconds_inline

So using 3 instead of 2 seconds as an interval on the Phantom 4 RTK is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation your parameters are valid under the condition the file format is set to JPEG.

Did you already check the file format of the photos? According to the documentation when the file format is RAW or RAW+JPEG, the valid range for the shoot interval is [10, 2^16 - 1] seconds. If you didn't change the format, maybe the drone changed the settings to default or something by itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The piece of code above is within another piece of code which sets the format to JPEG, so this piece of code is only executed when setting JPEG was successful.

Comment: Well, this is really frustrating then. Maybe try to wait 100ms after setting to JPEG was successful before setPhotoTimeIntervalSettings(). From my experience the SDK/aircraft sometimes needs a bit more time before applying the settings even though the callback returned successful.

Comment: I just tried it with 500ms between all the steps (Setting file format, setting image ratio, setting shoot photo mode and setting interval) but that also didn't help. Thanks a lot for the tipp though!